# Extracting values over a large area in Google Earth Engine: memory optimisation

Tags: google-earth-engine, sampling

I am trying to sample satellite (Sentinel-2 spectral metrics) data over a rather large area (1500 by 2500 km). I have around 2000 points relatively evenly distributed over this area.

However, even after increasing the *TileScale* and going through the GEE debugging guide, I get *User memory limit exceeded* errors.
Is there any way to optimise it?
I used the same code over a smaller area (500 by 200 km), and it worked just fine.
I also tried to map over the collection, sampling data for individual points, but it takes ages...

Here is my code:

```
// CLOUD MASKING
var getQABits = function(image, start, end, newName) {
  var pattern = 0;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) { 
    pattern += Math.pow(2, i);
  }
  return image.select([0], [newName])
              .bitwiseAnd(pattern)
              .rightShift(start);
  };
var cmask = function(img) {
  var QA = img.select('QA60'); 
  var opaque = getQABits(QA, 10, 10, 'opaque').eq(0);
  var cirrus = getQABits(QA, 11, 11, 'cirrus').eq(0);
  img = img.updateMask(opaque).updateMask(cirrus).copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames());
  return img;
};
// PREPROCESSING
var col_noclouds = s2.filterBounds(pixels)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
    .filterDate('2018-10-30', '2023-10-30')
    .map(cmask)
    .map(function(image) {
      var ndmi = image.expression('(NIR - SWIR)/(NIR + SWIR)', {
        'NIR': image.select('B8'),
        'SWIR': image.select('B12')
      }).multiply(1000).toInt().rename('NDMI');
      var ndvi = image.expression('(NIR - R)/(NIR + R)', {
        'NIR': image.select('B8'),
        'R': image.select('B4')
      }).multiply(1000).toInt().rename('NDVI');
      return image.addBands(ndmi).addBands(ndvi).copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
    })
    .select('B4', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'NDVI', 'NDMI');

var reducers = ee.Reducer.median().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([25]),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([75]),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([90]),
  sharedInputs: true
});

var yr = col_noclouds.reduce(reducers);
var names = yr.bandNames();
var yrNames = names.map(function(name){
  return ee.String(name).cat('_yr');
});
var yr = yr.rename(yrNames);

    
// REDUCTION 

var stats_yr = yr.reduceRegions({
    collection: pixels,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 10,
    crs: 'EPSG:3857',
    tileScale: 16
});

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: stats_yr,
  description: 'water_yr',
  folder: 'results',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some bad practices in here, but the main problem is this:

```
.copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
```

You're indiscriminately duplicating a bunch of metadata on thousands of images, that you're then not using any of it.  But that all takes memory.  So, don't do that.

Also, combine your `percentile` reducers.  You're already correctly "combining" them, but percentile can actually take a list of percentiles to compute, in one go (median is equal to the 50th percentile, too).  The way you're doing it, it's making 4 separate histograms per pixel, one for each reducer. Each of which is expensive.

```
var reducers = ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.percentile([25, 50, 75, 90]),
  sharedInputs: true
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/c00b600922ce50430e8a8b1bcc3c035f

Comment: Thanks! This indeed made it work!